# Codenameone showForm not recognized in second form?

Tags: codenameone

In my `StateMachine class` I can use `showForm("form2",null)` to load a second form which loads the next form. In this next form I have a form2 class but if I try to do a showForm in this class the command is not recognized. So how do I call a form from a different class or does everything have to go through StateMachine?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which command isn't recognized and what's in that class? 
Notice that you are using the old GUI builder where forms don't map to classes

Comment: Ah that's the key "old GUI builder"! I am now using the new GUI builder and this has solved my problem. Nice! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

you can use show form2

```
Form form2 = new Form();
form2.show();
```

and you can pass an object of Statemachine (stateMachine) to Form1 then call

```
stateMachine.showForm("NewForm", null); // NewForm should be created in designer theme.
```